# php вывод всех значений массива из функции

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые знатоки.

Необходимо написать функцию, которая создает массив из случайных чисел и возвращает в отсортированном по убыванию порядку.

Внимание вопрос: Как вывести все значения из массива?

```
function massive($m) {   

    $mass = [];
    $znach = mt_rand(10, 20);
    for($i=0; $i<$m; $i++) {
        $mass[] = mt_rand(1, 30);
    }
    rsort($mass);
    foreach($mass as $key=> $value) {
        return $value."<br>"
    }
    return;
}

echo massive(6)."\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

**Разумеется**, никаких строк из функции возвращать не надо. Чтобы вывести все значения массива из функции, функция должна возвращать... массив! И уже потом этот массив можно выводить любым из миллионов доступных способов.  Включая print_r, implode и наиболее гибкий - **`foreach`, который и является стандартным ответом на вопрос, "как вывести все значения из массива"**:

```
function massive($m)
{   
    $mass = [];
    for($i=0; $i<$m; $i++) {
        $mass[] = mt_rand(1, 30);
    }
    rsort($mass);
    return $mass;
}
$array = massive(6);
echo implode(', ', $array), "<br>\n";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($array as $item)
{
    echo "$item<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого удобно воспользоваться функцией `implode()`, которая позволяет преобразовать массив в строку с разделителем, заданным в первом аргументе

```
function massive($m) {   

    $mass = [];
    $znach = mt_rand(10, 20);
    for($i=0; $i<$m; $i++) {
        $mass[] = mt_rand(1, 30);
    }
    rsort($mass);
    return implode(', ', $mass)
}

echo massive(6)."\n";
```

Comment: Благодарю! Благодаря Вашему редактированию вопроса, я еще узнал, как правильно оформлять вопрос :)

Comment: Не надо учить новичков возвращать массив из функции в виде строки. @Demiteli, не следует пользоваться этим ответом.

Comment: Не надо учить учить отвечать на вопросы и пользоваться ответами.

Answer (score 0):

как дополнение к предыдущему ответу просто воспользоваться `print_r` который выведет полностью массив.

```
function massive($m) {   

    $mass = [];
    $znach = mt_rand(10, 20);
    for($i=0; $i<$m; $i++) {
        $mass[] = mt_rand(1, 30);
    }
    rsort($mass);
    return $mass;
}

print_r(massive(6))."\n";
```